# VBA import data: exclude sheet if doesn't exist

Tags: vba, loops, import

I have built this code which import data from a workbook and paste it to another one. The original workbook is composed by hundred of sheets (one sheet for each country, identified by the ISO 2 digit code: AE, AL, AM, AR etc...). The macro is opening each one of these sheets, copying the same cell, and printing all these cells in a new workbook.
The problem is that if, for example, the sheet F(AM) doesn't exists, the macro stops. I would like to make sure that if a sheet doesn't exist, the macro continues with all the other sheets (namely F(AR), F(AT), F(AU)) till the end.
Someone has any suggestion?
Many thanks in advance!

```
    Sub ImportData()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim MainBook As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Dim SheetName As String

    'Specify input data
    Path = Worksheets("Input").Range("C6").Value
    'Decide in which target sheet print the results
    SheetName = "Data"
    'From which sheets you need to take the data?
    OriginSheet145 = "F(AE)"
    OriginSheet146 = "F(AL)"
    OriginSheet147 = "F(AM)"
    OriginSheet148 = "F(AR)"
    OriginSheet149 = "F(AT)"
    OriginSheet150 = "F(AU)"
    'Set the origin workbook
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Path & "_20171231.xlsx")
    'Set the target workbook
    Set MainBook = ThisWorkbook

    'Vlookup to identify the correct data point
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet145).Range("N25").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet146).Range("N26").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet147).Range("N27").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet148).Range("N28").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet149).Range("N29").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet150).Range("N30").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""010"",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)"
    'Copy the data point and paste in the target sheet
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet145).Range("N25").Copy
    MainBook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("AW5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet146).Range("N26").Copy
    MainBook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("AW6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet147).Range("N27").Copy
    MainBook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("AW7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet148).Range("N28").Copy
    MainBook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("AW8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet149).Range("N29").Copy
    MainBook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("AW9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Wb1.Sheets(OriginSheet150).Range("N30").Copy

    MainBook.Save
    Wb1.Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox "Data: imported!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here but I'm sure there is a better approach.  What are `OriginSheet145` thru `OriginSheet150` and where are they set? Do they change?  You're copying a hard-coded formula (`=VLOOKUP("010",C[-10]:C[-7],2,FALSE)`) to 6 cells, then copying those cells somewhere else??

Comment: `OriginSheet` are the original sheets from where the macro is taking the data. The names of these sheets change (F(AE), F(AL), F(AM)...) but inside the structure of the sheets is always the same for all of them. So for each of these sheets, the code is taking a data point (identified via VLOOKUP), copying the data point from the `OriginSheet` and pasting in the target workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, indicating whether a worksheet named in *string* `wsName` exists in workbook *object*

```
Function wsExists(wb As Workbook, wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws: For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    wsExists = (wsName = ws.Name): If wsExists Then Exit For
    Next ws
End Function
```

Us an `IF` statement to skip the applicable code if the worksheet does not exist.

---

### Edit:

I can tell that you put a lot of work into your code, which is awesome, so don't take it the wrong way when I say it gave me anxiety so I had to simplify it. ...there are a lot of unneeded steps.

I do believe the "right way" is "whatever way works", so kudo's on getting this far. There's a steep learning curve in programming, so I figured I'd offer an alternate code block to replace yours. (The `Option Explicit` goes at the very top of the module, and will "force" you to properly declare/handle variables, objects, etc.)

Without seeing your data I can't guarantee this will work - in fact it very likely a cell reference wrong somewhere that you'll have to try to figure out - if you choose to use this at all.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    Const SheetName = "Data" 'destination sheet name
    Const sourceFile = "_20171231.xlsx" 'source filename for some reason
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook, sht As Variant
    Dim stPath As String, arrSourceSht() As Variant, inRow As Long

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook 'dest wb object
    stPath = Worksheets("Input").Range("C6").Value 'source wb stPath
    'create array of source sheet names "146-150":
    arrSourceSht = Array("F(AE)", "F(AL)", "F(AM)", "F(AR)", "F(AT)", "F(AU)")
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(stPath & sourceFile) 'open source wb

    With wbSrc
        'VLookup to identify the correct data point
        inRow = 5 'current input row
        For Each sht In arrSourceSht
            If wsExists(wbSrc, CStr(sht)) Then
                wbDest.Sheets(sht).Range("AW" & inRow) = Application._
                  WorksheetFunction.VLookup("010", Range(.Sheets(sht).Range("N" & _
                  20 + inRow).Offset(-10), .Sheets(sht).Range("N" & 20 + inRow).Offset(-7)), 2, False)
            End If
            inRow = inRow + 1 'new input row
        Next sht

        wbDest.Save 'save dest
        .Close savechanges:=False 'don't save source

    End With
    MsgBox "Data: imported!"

End Sub

Function wsExists(wb As Workbook, wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws: For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    wsExists = (wsName = ws.Name): If wsExists Then Exit For
    Next ws
End Function
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I can walk you through how it works if you like.  (I'm on here at least once a day.)